# HttpResponseMessage Not Returning any response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asynchronous

Im trying connect to a API and get the data from it. But Im not getting Anything after HttpResponseMessage code line.if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) never runs. I have tried everything, but nothing yet. please help. This is my code.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft;
using System.Net.Http.Headers; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Net.Http; 
using System.Web; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Xml;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace JKLLAppMobile.API
{
public class JKLLAPI : Controller
{
    public async Task<List<JasonData>> MakeRequest()
    {
        List<JasonData> HanaData = new List<JasonData>();

        var client = new HttpClient();
        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        queryString["format"] = "json";
        queryString["filter"] = "BDATU eq '20170421' and BWLVS eq '609'";
        var uri = "https://jkhapimdev.azure-api.net/api/beta/v2/bound/?" + queryString;

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{Token-Key}");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            string json_data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseString); 


        }

        return HanaData;
    }
}
```

}

Calling Ajax Method
    function TotalTestMonthly() {

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '../JKLLAPI/MakeRequest',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        data: {},
        success: function (data) { 
            if (data.Success == true) {

            } 
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Google configureAwait / async task deadlock. I'd add an answer but I'm in bed. Basically the source thread is waiting for the http thread is waiting for the source thread. that's likely your issue.

Comment: Here's an [article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) by Stephen Cleary which explains it.

Comment: @john are you still in dreams.. comeon man giving some weird answer. Wake up kiddo..

Comment: @lone at least I'm giving the right answer. And I'm about to go to sleep since it's 2:37am in Japan :)

Comment: I'd be surprised if this scenario was a deadlock

Comment: @john Thank you, i'll try that. but please put an answer when you can.

Comment: Have you had a look at the request in fiddler to see if the request ever gets a response

Comment: @Stuart Yes i did, i wrote the same code in a console app. And i got the data. but in in here with mvc, not getting the response.

Comment: @john Have a good one bro... I would think that he is missing some auth key, tracing the request from restclient or similar tools will narrow down the error.

Comment: Ok, i take it you are calling this from an action method? Could you show us that code? I am now suspecting John is right if you are calling this but blocking on it

Comment: Im calling this from ajax call, Updated. Check now.

Comment: It works in a console application, because a console application doesn't have any context, that can cause a deadlock. Like john wrote, you have to use ConfigureAwait, like this:  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false); I wish you luck with that. ;) @john Now it is 2:42am in german. ;)

Comment: I have tried HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false); It returns false always with no data.

Comment: @DinukshiJayarathne That's really another question now, but to be honest it's specific to the API you're using. When a request is unsuccessful (i.e. the server returns a non-success status code), you can still read the response content. I just tried with your URL and got an error message stating "Resource not found".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have said it "never" runs the IsSuccessStatusCode line, not even for after a timeout, I'd guess that you have a deadlock situation happening.

As I commented above, Stephen Cleary has a really good [article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) which describes the problem. He has also penned an [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

To summarise (in case the linked articles ever disappear):

- When you make an async call the current SynchronizationContext (or, if it's null, the TaskScheduler) is captured as a kind of return point for the async call.
- GUI and ASP.NET applications use SynchronizationContext. This only allows one block of synchronous code to run at once.
- Once your async task has completed, it will try to return to the SynchronizationContext, which, if you're starting from a non-async position, will be blocked on `someTask.Wait();`
- Once you reach this point, you have a situation where your synchronous code is waiting for your asynchronous code, and your asynchronous code is waiting to return to your synchronous code, causing a deadlock.

Note: According to Stephen's MSDN article, console applications do not have this issue because they use the TaskScheduler. VS' Unit Test task runner does have this issue, which is how I learned of it.

---

So, what can you do?

If  you're running async from a GUI context, e.g. a button click, you should change your button click handler to an async method:

```
// you can't change void to Task because of the type the delegate expects,
// but this is the correct way to do this.
public async void OnClicked(...)
```

You can then use the standard await, and the context is handled as you would expect.

In your async methods you can call ConfigureAwait:

```
await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
// or, simply:
await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This causes the method to execute the rest of the async method in the Thread Pool context, which averts the deadlock.

If for some reason you can't handle, or wrap, the async method, then you can also use `Task.Run`:

```
// You can also use Task<string>.Run(...), for example
var task = Task.Run(async () => await someAsyncMethod());
task.Wait();
```

Using Task.Run will execute the async method within the Thread Pool context, and thus avoid the deadlock.

My explanation really doesn't do the topic justice, so I highly recommend reading the articles I linked above. I just wanted to make sure my answer contained some valuable content if the links were to ever disappear :-)

**Note** The correct way to do async is async all the way down (i.e. from the button click to the deepest async call). Task.Run shouldn't be used *within* an async method.

---

I've put together my own quick example to demonstrate these techniques:

```
// Deadlocks
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var task = GetNews();
    task.Wait();
    MessageBox.Show(task.Result);
}

// Doesn't deadlock
public async void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = await GetNews();
    MessageBox.Show(result);
}

// Doesn't deadlock
public void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var task = GetNews(false);
    task.Wait();
    MessageBox.Show(task.Result);
}

// Doesn't deadlock
public void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var task = Task<string>.Run(async () => await GetNews());
    task.Wait();
    MessageBox.Show(task.Result);
}

// The boolean option is just so that I don't have to write two example methods :)
// You obviously don't have to pass this as a parameter, and can just directly call ConfigureAwait
public async Task<string> GetNews(bool continueOnCapturedContext = true)
{
    await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: continueOnCapturedContext);
    return "hello";
}
```

Comment: This is a very good explaination, however given the code we have been given, where is the blocking? This doesn't fit, unless we haven't got all the code

Comment: @Stuart Well, before he said it was never reaching IsSuccessStatusCode and now he says that it's always returning false, so the evidence seems to point to that. We could do with all of the code to make the question better, of course.

Comment: If you're asking why I felt like it was this, it's because the HttpClient has a default timeout of 100 seconds, and if that's never being reached (the OP said it was never reaching his if statement), then it must be deadlocking (since actually receiving the data is handled afterwards).

Comment: Totally agree @john